# Determine height of tabular

Tags: tables, height

I am working in a minipage, because I want two columns next to each other in landscape mode.

In the first column I would like to place a figure, and then a tabular. I am scaling the tabular to exactly fit the minipage. This is roughly the outline:

```
\newpage
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
% latex table generated in R 2.14.1 by xtable 1.6-0 package
% Thu Nov  8 13:31:32 2012
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
```

What I now would like to do is plot the remaining figure in exactly the correct proportions to fill the remainder of the page - the width is fairly easy, but what is the height? The problem is also that I don't know the number of rows of the table in advance.

So I need some way to determine the height of the tabular, subtract it from the textheight, to obtain my remaining space for the figure.

`\settoheight` unfortunately only works on text.

Comment: as with any latex construct you can put it in a box and measure the `\ht` of the box, which is exactly the definition of `\settoheight`. I'm not sure why you say that only works on text, the box measurement doesn't know what is inside the box, it can be text tables, graphics, anything that latex can typeset.

Comment: Also if you want your two minipages to fit side by side you need a `%` after `\end{minipage}` as you have a word space between them and you can not get two `0.5\textwidth` boxes and a word space on one line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks! The reason I thought it wouldn't work was [the help](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-311.html) where it specifically mentions text.

Comment: LaTeX thinks more or less anything is text: a table is just a big letter....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that `\settoheight` measures the height, but tabular environments also have a depth; so we need to take also the depth into account. Here's a proposal; the total height of the (resized) table is stored in the register `\tableheight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\newlength{\tableheight}
\newenvironment{resizedtabular}[1]
 {\begin{lrbox}{\tablebox}\begin{tabular}{#1}}
 {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}%
  \sbox{\tablebox}{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\tablebox}}}%
  \global\tableheight=\ht\tablebox
  \global\advance\tableheight\dp\tablebox
  \usebox{\tablebox}}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{resizedtabular}{lll}
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi
\end{resizedtabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\tableheight]{a}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{resizedtabular}{llllll}
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi \\
abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi & abcabcabc & defdefdef & ghighighi
\end{resizedtabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\tableheight]{a}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is to answer

> `\settoheight` unfortunately only works on text.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\mylength}
\settoheight{\mylength}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\the\mylength
\end{document}
```

The result is `26.5pt`. Hence `\settoheight` works!

Answer (score 2):

Does something like the following help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\testtbl}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
test & test\\
test & test
\end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\ntabht}{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\testtbl} \the\ht0%
}

\begin{document}
\ntabht
\end{document}
```

Notice that this will print the height of the table which in this case is `14.5pt`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `calc`'s package `\totalheightof` (compute sum of height and depth):

```
\usepackage{calc}
...
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mytable}{
    \begin{tabular}{...}
        [YOUR TABLE]
    \end{tabular}
}
...
\begin{document}
...
\newlength{\mytableheigth}
\setlength{\mytableheigth}{\totalheightof{\mytable}}
```