# How to align tikzpicture and table?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd need to have the tikzpicture of the same height of the table (between \toprule and \bottomrule) and in the position shown in the picture. Do you know how can I dot that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage,usenames,dvipsnames,draft]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.eps,.fig}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\documentclass{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
%\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm, right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\textbf{Categories} & \textbf{QR} &\textbf{weigh}t & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{Xiaomi}} & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{HONOR}} & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{HUAWEI}} & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{Fitbit}} \\ \toprule
\multirow{4}{*}{functionality} & lightness &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & durability &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & accuracy &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & battery life &  &  &  &  &  \\
safety & biocompatibility &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
\multirow{7}{*}{comfort and usability} & surface softness &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 & grip &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & easiness &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & waterproof &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & washability &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & breathability &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & heat/cold resistance &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 design& style &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 \multirow{2}{*}{pleasure}& screen size &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & ecological &  &  &  &  & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
 %transpose legend,
     %legend columns=1,
     %legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},%%%
            xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
            ymin = 0, ymax = 16,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
            xtick distance = 1,
            ytick distance = 1,
     grid = both,
     %title= Relative angle,
            %minor tick num = 1,
            major grid style = {lightgray},
            minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
            width = 0.26\textwidth,
            height = 0.734\textwidth,
            %xlabel = {$x$},
            %ylabel = {$y$},
           % legend cell align = {left},
        ]
           % \addplot[
               % domain = 0:30,
                %samples = 200,
                %smooth,
                %thick,
                %blue,
            %] {exp(-x/10)*( cos(deg(x)) + sin(deg(x))/10 )};
             \addplot[
                %smooth,
                thick,
                red,
        mark=*,
                %dashed
            ] file[skip first] {xiaomi.dat};

\addplot[
                %smooth,
                thick,
                blue,
        mark=square,
                %dashed
            ] file[skip first] {honor.dat};
\addplot[
                %smooth,
                thick,
                green,
        mark=triangle,
                %dashed
            ] file[skip first] {huawei.dat};
\addplot[
                %smooth,
                thick,
                yellow,
        mark=x,
                %dashed
            ] file[skip first] {fitbit.dat};

            %\legend{Huawei}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the .dat files you can use the same one four times:

```
x         y
 2       0.5         
 4      1.5
 3      2.5
 2      3.5
 1      4.5
 1      5.5
 2      6.5
 3      7.5 
 4      8.5 
 2      9.5
 3      10.5    
 3      11.5
 4      12.5
 1      13.5
 3      14.5
 1      15.5
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you to get started: [Determine height of tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81999/90202). You can then use `\resizebox{!}{\tableheight}{...}` around your `tikzpicture`

Comment: The main problem is not the size, but how to align the two parts

Comment: Do the individual data points in the diagram correnalte with the table rows?

Comment: how? I'm kinda new to LaTeX ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some approximation of desired table ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage,usenames,dvipsnames,draft]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            left=30mm, right=25mm,
            top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\newsavebox{\tabox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{xiaomi.dat}
x         y
 2      0.5
 4      1.5
 3      2.5
 2      3.5
 1      4.5
 1      5.5
 2      6.5
 3      7.5
 4      8.5
 2      9.5
 3      10.5
 3      11.5
 4      12.5
 1      13.5
 3      14.5
 1      15.5
\end{filecontents*}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\sbox\tabox{
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont HUAWEI }
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\linewidth}[b]{@{} XX ccccc c @{}}
\thead{Categories} 
    & \thead{QR} 
        &\thead{weight}
            & \rothead{\emph{Xiaomi}} 
                & \rothead{\emph{HONOR}} 
                    & \rothead{\emph{HUAWEI}} 
                            & \rothead{\emph{Fitb}} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{4}{=}{functionality} 
    & lightness             &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & durability            &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & accuracy              &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & battery life          &   &   &   &   &   \\
safety 
    & biocompatibility      &   &   &   &   &   \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-7}
\multirow{7}{=}{comfort and usability} 
    & surface softness      &   &   &   &   &   \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-7}
    & grip                  &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & easiness              &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & waterproof            &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & washability           &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & breathability         &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & heat/cold resistance  &   &   &   &   &   \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-7}
design
    & style                 &   &   &   &   &   \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-7}
\multirow{2}{=}{pleasure}
    & screen size           &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & ecological            &   &   &   &   &   \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
%
\usebox\tabox\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 16,
        width=44mm, height=\dimexpr\ht\tabox+\dp\tabox-\baselineskip,
        xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
        grid=both,
        minor tick num = 4,
        major grid style = {lightgray},
        minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
                    ]
        \addplot +[thick] file[skip first] {xiaomi.dat};
        \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Height of diagram is measured by help of `\tabox` where is stored table (`\ht\tabox + \hp\tabox`). Aligned is at bottom of table.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the appropriate points in the tabular using `\tikzmark`.  You can compute the distance between the two points using PGF macros.  Finally, you can put the tikzpicture into a savebox and scale it using `\resizebox` (graphicx package).  In this case I used `\includegraphics` instead, since the pgfplot provided won't run.

The 3pt and 2pt are fudge factors.  I didn't want to dig through booktabs to find the actual values.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage,usenames,dvipsnames]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.eps,.fig}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor}% duplicate
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
%\usepackage{amsmath}% duplicate
%\documentclass{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
%\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}% should go last
\usepackage{siunitx}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm, right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}% duplicate

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{cccccccl@{}}
\textbf{Categories} & \textbf{QR} &\textbf{weigh}t & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{Xiaomi}} & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{HONOR}} & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{HUAWEI}} & \rotatebox{90}{\emph{Fitbit}} \\ \toprule
\multirow{4}{*}{functionality} & lightness &  &  &  &  & & \tikzmark{top}\\
 & durability &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & accuracy &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & battery life &  &  &  &  &  \\
safety & biocompatibility &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
\multirow{7}{*}{comfort and usability} & surface softness &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 & grip &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & easiness &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & waterproof &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & washability &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & breathability &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & heat/cold resistance &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 design& style &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
 \multirow{2}{*}{pleasure}& screen size &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & ecological &  &  &  &  & & \tikzmark{bottom} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \path (pic cs:top) ++ (0pt,\arraystretch\ht\strutbox+3pt) coordinate (top);
  \path (pic cs:bottom) ++ (0pt,-\arraystretch\dp\strutbox-2pt) coordinate (bottom);
  %\draw[red] (top) -- (bottom);% test run
  \pgfextracty{\tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{bottom}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{top}{center}}}%
  \node[below right, inner sep=0pt] at (top) {\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=\tempdima]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]